# Subquery returning incorrect value

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me preface this by saying that I am a manager and I haven't done this kind of work for quite awhile, as you'll see.  But for various reasons, I'm having to cover some of the SQL programming until I get more headcount.  Yes, I'll say upfront that I am an incompetent idiot in this area.

What I have is a very, very long SQL statement, with a whole bunch of selects from various tables, and assorted subqueries.  The query has about 400 lines.  It worked fine, until I tried to add a certain subquery.  That subquery is returning the wrong value.  When I break the subquery into a couple of shorter test queries to troubleshoot, they return the correct value.  It's the combined one that doesn't work.  I'm sure it must be related to the way I'm joining.

I'm trying to get total revenue amount that is stored in two tables:  one table has current values in it, and the other one has historical values.  The values are on a customer level, and the customer table is one-to-many with both of the others.  The two revenue tables are structured identically and there are no records in common.  One is a historical archive for the other.  All I want to do is sum up the revenue values between the two tables on a customer level.

Here is the subquery that doesn't work. It should be the sum of the current_revenue and historical_revenue:

```
select c.id1, c.id2,
(select (sum(oe.revenue1)+sum(oe.revenue2)+sum(h.revenue1)+sum(h.revenue2))*.01 
     from order_entry oe, order_history h
     where c.id1 = oe.id1
     and c.id2 = oe.id2
     and c.id1 = h.id1
     and c.id2 = h.id2
     and oe.order_type in ('01','02','03','04')
     and oe.order_status = 'CLOSED'
     and h.order_type in ('01','02','03','04')
     and h.order_status = 'CLOSED') as total_revenue
from customer c
where c.id1 = '1234'
and c.id2 = '5678'
--query incorrectly returns $4460      
--this query is adding the $1500 in twice (see below)
```

Here are the two test queries that do work.  They are identical except for table name:

```
select c.id1, c.id2,
(select (sum(oe.revenue1)+sum(oe.revenue2))*.01
     from order_entry oe
     where c.id1 = oe.id1
     and c.id2 = oe.id2
     and oe.order_type in ('01','02','03','04')
     and oe.order_status = 'CLOSED') as current_revenue
from customer c
where c.id1 = '1234'
and c.id2 = '5678'
--query correctly returns $1460


select c.id1, c.id2,
(select (sum(h.revenue1)+sum(h.revenue2))*.01
     from order_history h
     where c.id1 = h.id1
     and c.id2 = h.id2
     and h.order_type in ('01','02','03','04')
     and h.order_status = 'CLOSED') as historical_revenue
from customer c
where c.id1 = '1234'
and c.id2 = '5678'
--query correctly returns $1500

/*
these will be subqueries in another query which needs to return
total revenue = current_revenue + historical_revenue = 1460 + 1500 = 2960
*/
```

Can somebody tell me why the combined subquery doesn't work?  Again, I freely confess my stupidity upfront.  I'm sure I'm going to feel like a complete idiot later, but I just need some help.  Thanks.

EDIT:  Sample table creates & inserts.  Tables are poorly designed.  And very large.  Hence the samples.  Note, too, that the largeness of the SQL statement I'm building is that I'm pulling around 10MM records in the select for a data feed, which turns out to be faster than breaking it up and updating.  There's nothing reasonable to partition on in terms of creating multiple tables that could be joined with union at the end.  I've tried various things, but the ginormous select is turning out to be the fastest.  I'm not really all that adept at SQL turning either, as you've noticed, including optimizer hints.

Thanks, Clockwork Muse, for the help...I'm going to test your solution shortly.  Also, no dedicated reporting tool available.

```
create table customer (id1 varchar2(4),id2 varchar2(4), 
first_name varchar2(30),last_name varchar2(30));

insert into customer values ('1234','5678','DAVID','HOOVER');
insert into customer values ('0676','3724','JOHN','BOWER');
insert into customer values ('7281','1766','ANNA','VALENZUELA');
insert into customer values ('1458','0076','MARK','JACKSON');
insert into customer values ('0003','9783','JESSICA','BURNETT');

create table order_entry (id1 varchar2(4),id2 varchar2(4),
order_no number,order_type varchar2(2),order_status varchar2(10), 
revenue1 number(10),revenue2(10));

insert into order_entry values ('1234','5678',238347,'02','CLOSED',1220,0;
insert into order_entry values ('1234','5678',238347,'02','CLOSED',0,240;
insert into order_entry values ('1234','5678',238529,'05','CANCEL',500,700;
insert into order_entry values ('1234','5678',238529,'04','PENDING',871,0;
insert into order_entry values ('0003','9783',198293,'33','CLOSED',870,50;
insert into order_entry values ('0676','3724',219972,'02','CLOSED',375,0;
insert into order_entry values ('0676','3724',219972,'02','PENDING',175,59;
insert into order_entry values ('7281','1766',248221,'04','PENDING',0,999;
insert into order_entry values ('1458','0076',218578,'04','CLOSED',0,99;
insert into order_entry values ('1458','0076',218578,'02','CLOSED',399,0;


create table order_history (id1 varchar2(4),id2 varchar2(4),
order_no number,order_type varchar2(2),order_status varchar2(10), 
revenue1 number(10),revenue2(10));

insert into order_history values ('1234','5678',192832,'01','CLOSED',750,0;
insert into order_history values ('1234','5678',192991,'02','CLOSED',0,750;
insert into order_history values ('0003','9783',138982,'01','CLOSED',299,0;
insert into order_history values ('0676','3724',112729,'01','CLOSED',350,0;
insert into order_history values ('1458','0076',185573,'01','CANCEL',1299,199;
```

Comment: The problem is caused by joins. For example, there is one row in `h` totaling $1500, and two rows in `oe` totaling $1460. Join creates the product of these rows - in this case it duplicates `h` row. This is the reason aggregates are usually done only on `n` side of `1:n` joins. Solution is to do the aggregating before the join using derived tables or ctes.

Comment: if possible please provide sample data for 3 of the tables, thank you

Comment: Oh, and to be clear, the freakishly long 400 line SQL query is a CTAS.  It's structured like this:  select col1, col2, col3, col4, (select x from y bunch of where clauses) as col5, col6, col7, (select a from b bunch of where clauses) as col8, and so on.  Previously, I created the 10MM rec table and spooled it out, and it wasn't too bad.  Then I had to add this whole aggregated revenue piece to it, which is when it started breaking down.  Thanks...

Comment: And Nikola, I was thinking that because the order_entry and order_history tables use the same DDL, I could easily select off the attributes I need and join the tables in a union as a derived table, and use that in the from clause.  However, I'm pulling data for 10MM unique customers, and each has multiple orders, so I'm thinking the derived table would be probably 40-50MM recs.  Do you think that would get better performance than what I'm trying to do here?  Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should be explicitly qualifying your joins, not using the implicit-join (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax.  This won't actually solve your problem in itself, but it may make future work easier - especially because other than 'normal' inner-joins, anything else gets more difficult/slightly weird.

The problem, as @Nikola mentioned, is that you're getting 'duplicate' rows.  You have two solutions:

1. Add conditions to the join, until there will no longer be duplicate rows (note that this can be difficult/impossible if there is a mismatch between unique information in the tables!)
2. Perform the aggregation *before* the join, guaranteeing single rows for the join.

Performance of either option may be better or worse, depending on a large number of factors.

Without more information about your data, it's impossible to say if additional conditions could be added to properly 'unique' the rows (given that it probably has something to do with the `order_type` column, I'm not sure it's even possible).  So, here's a pre-aggregate version (untested):

```
SELECT c.id1, c.id2, (current_revenue.revenue + historical_revenue.revenue) * .01
FROM Customer c
JOIN (SELECT id1, id2, SUM(revenue1 + revenue2) as revenue
      FROM Order_Entry
      WHERE order_type in ('01', '02', '03', '04')
      AND order_status = 'CLOSED'
      GROUP BY id1, id2) as current_revenue
ON current_revenue.id1 = c.id1
   AND current_revenue.id2 = c.id2
JOIN (SELECT id1, id2, SUM(revenue1 + revenue2) as revenue
      FROM Order_History
      WHERE order_type in ('01', '02', '03', '04')
      AND order_status = 'CLOSED'
      GROUP BY id1, id2) as historical_revenue
ON historical_revenue.id1 = c.id1
   AND historical_revenue.id2 = c.id2
WHERE c.id1 = '1234'
      AND c.id2 = '5678'
```

Note that I'm not sure if Oracle is smart enough to apply the customer-id restriction *before* performing the aggregate - that is, the RDBMS may perform the aggregate over the *entire* table, instead of just the rows for that customer.  There are a couple of ways to deal with that eventuality; either move the sub-queries into the `SELECT` clause, or add the customer id selection into the subselects themselves.

... Also, 400 lines is **freakishly long**.  Are you sure you wouldn't be better off breaking it up somehow, or investing in something like a dedicated reporting tool?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest possible solution : if you already count 2 correct values, just sum it:

([SQLFiddle for test](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b3e51/6))

```
select c.id1, c.id2,
  (
    (select (sum(oe.revenue1)+sum(oe.revenue2)) * 0.01  -- current_revenue
         from order_entry oe
         where c.id1 = oe.id1
         and c.id2 = oe.id2
         and oe.order_type in ('01','02','03','04')
         and oe.order_status = 'CLOSED'
    ) 
    +
    (select (sum(h.revenue1)+sum(h.revenue2))*.01    -- historical_revenue
         from order_history h
         where c.id1 = h.id1
         and c.id2 = h.id2
         and h.order_type in ('01','02','03','04')
         and h.order_status = 'CLOSED'
    )
  ) as total_revenue  
from customer c
where c.id1 = '1234'
and c.id2 = '5678'
```

Of course, it's impossible to guarantee optimal performance because of lack of data, but it's just working.